# interrupts on creating arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm creating a library for an energy counter. I want to count the pulses the energy counter produce and convert it to energy, through the arduino. To catch any pulse I want to use the arduino interrupts. I want it to be easy to use:

```
#include <EnergyCounter.h>

#define counterPin 2; // interrupt code 0 in Uno
EnergyCounter counter;

void setup(){
    counter.begin(counterPin);
}
...
```

Now, inside the *begin* method I want to attach an interrupt to the *counterPin*:

```
void EnergyCounter::begin(byte pin){
    pinMode(pin, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(0, countPulse, RISING);
}

void EnergyCounter::countPulse(){
    display += increment_per_pulse;
}
```

When I try it I get the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'EnergyCounter::countPulse' from type 'void (EnergyCounter::)()' to type 'void (*)()'
 attachInterrupt(0, countPulse, RISING);
                                      ^
Erro ao compilar.
```

Does this mean that I cannot use a method as Interrupt Service Routine (ISR)?
How can I solve the problem and yet have an easy to use interface to the library?

Comment: Did you try  `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(0), countPulse, RISING);` ?

Comment: I tryied but had same error

Comment: What about putting the function outside the class? I think that is a problem of conversion.

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Defining the function outside the class `void countPulse(){
    display += increment_per_pulse;
}`

Answer (score 1):

`increment_per_pulse` needs to be a static function (see the signature).

So, mark it `static`:

```
static void increment_per_pulse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside EnergyCounter class, define countPulse as static method, as below:

```
class EnergyCounter{
   //...
   static void countPulse();
   //...
};
```

Reason: ISR should be a function that returns void and has no parameters. Class member functions have a (hidden) parameter, that is a reference to the class instance.

Alternative solution is to move countPulse outside of EnergyCounter and make it just a regular method in the global namespace (not part of any class).